# How to write the below statement using (+) operator for left join

Tags: sql, oracle

```
LEFT  OUTER JOIN contact_lang ctLang ON con.CONTACT_ID=ctLang.CONTACT_ID AND ctLang.LANGUAGE_CODE = 'KOR'
```

HOW TO WRITE THE BELOW STATEMENT USING (+) operator for left join

Comment: Don't.  Why would you want to use an outdated syntax that's been archaic for a decade?

Comment: Every time I see some of our old code that still uses the (+) syntax, I have to do a google search to see what it means.  Speaking of google searches, what was your search string?

Comment: actually iit is a requirement in my project and i have to do it using +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This -

```
select *
  from contact con, contact_lang ctLang
 where con.CONTACT_ID = ctLang.CONTACT_ID(+)
   and ctLang.LANGUAGE_CODE(+) = 'KOR'
```